# How to step-down voltage without a transformer?

Tags: power-engineering

Say I am running a line from a transformer to a distribution panel that doesn't quite need 240V but less. How do you go about creating the required voltage drop?

I was asked this in a interview for my internship and he told me the answer to that is thicker ground wire?

Comment: Interviewer may be fishing for "longer/more resistive ground wire", but that's not really the right answer. Odd question.

Comment: @pjc50 By more resistive means thinner... I have a hunch he didn't like me. I interviewed with the CEO right after (which was an honor as this company is multi-national and he's not always present forget about interviewing an intern) and he gave me an OK and even said "welcome." After sometime when I called, they said they moved on... Anyhow, my question still stands till some mod remove this for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

Change the tapping on the transformer.

Comment: This is quite a short answer, could you edit with a few more details or references that might help the original poster?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to step down voltage without a transformer, is to add resistance to the circuit, whether that is by adding more length to the feeder, which would increase voltage drop,or by adding a resistor in the circuit. Either way, you are adding resistance, but with the resistor, you dont need more wire.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers are accepted or have any upvotes, and this question was bumped accordingly. So, I see no reason not to try a different answer.

I suppose a [capacitive divider](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Capacitive-voltage-divider.php) could be used in such a case?

[image: capacitive divider circuit]

It is not a great solution, but then again, it seems as if the question itself was not very well thought out. At least, it is a technically feasible and somewhat plausible approach that answers the question as posed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this *does* require a transformer.  However, the transformer that you use doesn't have to be rated for the full power of the load.  In other words, you can usually get by with a much smaller transformer.

Do a Google search for the word "autotransformer".  This is a transformer that either has a single winding that has a tap part way up the winding *OR* is a transformer where the secondary winding is in series with the incoming voltage.  The advantage of the 2nd configuration is that the transformer can be configured as a Boost or a Buck transformer just changing the phase relationship of the primary and secondary winding.

Note that the primary winding does NOT have to handle the full current of your load.  Only the secondary winding does.

Your situation is a common requirement for doing 208 Vac to 240 Vac conversion.  A single-winding 240V autotransformer with a tap at 208V is readily available from most electrical suppliers.

You can approximate the same thing by using a power transformer with 208V or 240V input (depending upon whether your input voltage is 208V or 240V) and then connecting the secondary winding in series with the input and then to your load.

Let's do a practical example.  You have a piece of equipment requiring 240 Vac and your building supply is 208 Vac 3-phase.  Your normal 120V loads aren't a problem because the phase-to-neutral voltage is 120 Vac.  But you've got this 240V load that just won't work properly from 208V.

Choose a transformer with a *SECONDARY* current rating greater than your connected load.  The primary voltage will be 208V and a very common secondary voltage is 24V.  208V + 24V is 232V.  This is well within the allowable range of your equipment.

Let's go further and assume that you want to have a full-load current rating of 15 Amps.  You will choose a transformer who's secondary winding is good for that current (or more).  The power rating of the transformer is (24V) * (15A) or 360 VA.  You will probably wind up purchasing a transformer rated at 500 VA, which is actually good for slightly more than 20 Amps.

But: note that the transformer is *much* smaller than you would think.  If your transformer had to handle the full 240V @ 15A, it would have to be rated at 3600 VA.  But because the transformer is handling only the *difference* in voltage rather than the full voltage, it can be much smaller.